How can I install Emacspeak?
I find some lengthy instructions on the website, but I also see that's it's available with use-package, but I get an error
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function ems-generate-switcher)
  (ems-generate-switcher 'emacspeak-toggle-comint-output-monitor 'emacspeak-comint-output-monitor "Toggle  Emacspeak comint monitor.\nInteractive PREF...")
  straight--activate-package-autoloads((:type git :host github :repo "emacsmirror/emacspeak" :package "emacspeak" :local-repo "emacspeak"))
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x3e04d585741863d>)()
  straight--transaction-exec(use-package-\"aa16322d8f05a75fc1c05b6a313aa48e\"-nil-nil :now #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x3e04d585741863d>))
  straight-use-package(emacspeak)
  (progn (straight-use-package 'emacspeak) (defvar use-package--warning310 #'(lambda (keyword err) (let ((msg (format "%s/%s: %s" ... keyword ...))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create "*use-package*")) (goto-char (point-max)) (insert "-----\n" msg "\n\n(use-package emacspeak :ensure t)\n\n  -->\n\n(use-p...") (emacs-lisp-mode)) (setq msg (concat msg " (see the *use-package* buffer)")) (display-warning 'use-package msg :error)))) (condition-case err (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package emacspeak") (prog1 (if (not (require 'emacspeak nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'emacspeak) :error)) (let ((elapsed (float-time ...))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package emacspeak" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package emacspeak"))))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning310 :catch err))))
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  #<subr eval-last-sexp>(nil)
  apply(#<subr eval-last-sexp> nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)


Or any other simpler instructions available than what is on their website?
I also find no proper tags to use, like "#emacspeak", #blind, for use on this topic.
EDIT; Ok, this works, if I launch emacs like this: emacspeak
, but I don't want to do that.
Is there something which needs to launch before starting Emacs, maybe?

"I don't want to do that": why don't you say what you want to do? If you mean you want to start it as a desktop app, then follow whatever steps are necessary for your platform. But note that's not an Emacs question, so ask it at the appropriate SE site. If you mean that you want to start/stop Emacspeak from within your standard Emacs, then say that (but I would ask on the Emacspeak Github site: there might be people here using it, but the likelihood of getting an answer will be much greater there - IMO).

.. and while you are at it, how about adding some links to the question? You have already searched and found them, so it doesn't cost you anything to add them. Learn how to ask good questions! Don't assume that we can read your mind.
